# doesnt set text value in android

Tags: android

Im new in andorid.I put textview to set data from mymethods.But it goes force close.But I tried it in another activity page my code worked.So ı suspected my xml layout .does anyone take care of this problem ,if so I will be very gratefull.Thanks Here are my layout.xml and my codes:

```
 String iskate=WorkCat.Kategori(Workid);
         iskat.setText(iskate);
       Log.d("işkategorisi",iskate);
```

> and Log.cat shows true value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgrund" >

    <!-- Header  Starts -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@layout/header" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Header Ends -->
    <!-- Footer Start -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@layout/footer" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagegeri"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:src="@drawable/geri" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagecikis"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cikis" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:text="Small Text"
      android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/textAD" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/header"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <TableLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="İş Kategorisi"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtiskate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="rfyr"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Aşama"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
                        </Spinner>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Görevli"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/Searchname"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        </AutoCompleteTextView>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Öncelik"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
                        </Spinner>
                    </TableRow>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edituacikla"
                        android:layout_width="290dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Gerçekleşen Süre"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edittoplm"
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner4"
                            android:ems="10"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Saat"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Tamamlanan(%)"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
                        </Spinner>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnvzgec"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Vazgec" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/uwgncelle"
                            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Güncelle" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which means iskat could be null. Did you initialize it?

Comment: have you find id of your textview? paste the error logcat here :)

Comment: TextView ad,iskat;  iskat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtiskate);then ı wrote the code.And I checked the textview id? and my logcat says null pointer iskat.

Comment: try with TextView iskat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtiskate);

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize your textview then after you can use it. Try below code.

```
TextView iskat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtiskate);
String iskate=WorkCat.Kategori(Workid);
iskat.setText(iskate);
```

Comment: @ozi Please log iskate value and be sure it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your Text View first

```
TextView iskat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtiskate);
String iskate=WorkCat.Kategori(Workid);
iskat.setText(iskate);
```

Comment: it is my logcat value:12-07 11:08:38.439: D/işkategorisi(736): Eğitim

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the right xml in the activity..i mean if you used findViewById with any other widget it's working

Comment: Yeah I checked it @Nunu,itis too strange.. ı tried to show toastmessage Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "value="+iskate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but nothing happened..ı cheched the layouts

Answer (score 0):

'iskate' should be instance of a 'TextView' like iskate=(TextView)(TextView)findViewById(id of the layout in xml here);
in your case its a string how is this possible this will show compile time error.

Comment: ı found my mistake.I had written setContentView(R.layout.uwrkdetail); after TextView iskat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtiskate).. so it didnt work.but then ı wrote setcon.. firstliy it worked :) thanks all of u :)